# Find id element inside JSON html content using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, json

I am returning JSON inside an ajax request which has html as one of its values.

```
html:
"<div id="foo">
    <p>FOO</p>
</div>

<div id="bar">
    <p>BAR</p>
</div>"
```

I would like to add `#foo` to one element and `#bar` to another. I have tried the following:

`$('#add-foo-html-here').html($(response.html).find('#foo'));`

but this fails to find `#foo`. What is the best way to do this? Should I be adding the html content to a temp element and then finding the id?

Comment: I'm guessing the element you are inserting to actually has the ID `#this` (does seem strange)? If the HTML is valid (there are some quoting issues above), it should work! Also, if they don't have a parent, you can't find() them, you'd need to append to them to an empty parent first.

Comment: Sorry that was just an example. I'll update it for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.filter()` instead of `.find()`.

```
$('#add-foo-html-here').html($(response.html).filter('#foo'));
```

`.find()` only find the children elements. But here `#foo` is not a child.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a parent to use `find()` ???

```
var div = $('<div />');
    div.html(response.html);

$('#elementID').html( div.find('#foo') );
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification with the find(). This is what I was going to do when creating the temp element.